# LIBGDX Custom Cursor

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm looking to change the cursor image to a custom image for the android game i'm creating using LIBGDX. Can anyone give me a hint on how to change the cursor from the default to a custom cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `setCursorImage()`in `Gdx.input`, for example:

```
Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("yourimage.png"));
int xHotSpot = pm.getWidth() / 2;
int yHotSpot = pm.getHeight() / 2;

Gdx.input.setCursorImage(pm, xHotSpot, yHotSpot);
pm.dispose();
```

Comment: not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

The API has been slightly changed:

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("cursor.png"));
int xHotspot = pixmap.getWidth() / 2;
int yHotspot = pixmap.getHeight() / 2;
Cursor cursor = Gdx.graphics.newCursor(pixmap, xHotspot, yHotspot);
Gdx.graphics.setCursor(cursor);
pixmap.dispose();
```